# How to add a class on a row on responsive-display?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to add a class on the row the user is clicking on. To do that, I use the `responsive-display` event.

```js
$(function () {
    $('#people-waiting-send-up').DataTable().on('responsive-display', function (e, datatable, row, showHide, update) {
        row.addClass('opened')
    });
});
```

But `row` is not a jQuery object so `addClass()` does not work. How should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `row.index`, I can find the row the user has clicked on, and add a class to it:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#people-waiting-send-up').DataTable().on('responsive-display', function (e, datatable, row, showHide, update) {
        $(datatable.row(row.index()).node()).addClass('opened');
    });
});
```